# In a Rails app, how can I make a link load in a div as opposed to refreshing the whole page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, link-to

I'm still a beginner at web development.  It's not my profession.  So go easy.

I started building a rails app today, and realized it would make my application so much better if I could get certain links to display in a separate div instead of a new page, or refreshing the entire page.  I'm not quite sure how to search for this, and I keep chasing red herrings with google.

Basically, I have a list in a div on the left side of the page, and when one item from that list is clicked, it should appear in the right div.  (Nothing else on the page need be changed)

That's really as simple as it is.  Do I need to use Javascript for this?  Can I get away with the rails js defaults, or should I be using JQuery?

Is there a way to do this without javascript?  I really just need a push in the right direction here, I'm tired of not even knowing how to search for this, or what documentation I should be reading.

Like I said, go easy, and you should just go ahead and err to the side of caution, and assume I know nothing.  Seriously.  :)

Thanks in advance,

-Kevin

(By the way, I'm developing with Rails 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your views (along with controllers) to be shown inside the div for each item on the left menu. Lets say we have the following structure now:

- Item1 (Clicking on it will fetch:
  http://myapp.com/item1)
- Item2  (Clicking on    it will fetch:
  http://myapp.com/item2)

and so on...
make sure you only render the html to be put inside your content div. Should not include `<head> <body> etc.` tags

In your main page you may have your markup like this >

```
<div id="leftMenu">
<a href="http://myapp.com/item1">Item 1</a>
<a href="http://myapp.com/item2">Item 2</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
Please click on an item on the left menu to load content here
</div>
```

Finally, add the following Javascript (you'll need jQuery; trust me it's a good decision).

```
$("#leftMenu a").click(function () {

   $("#content").load($(this).attr("href")); //load html from the url and put it in the #content element

   return false; //prevent the default href action

});
```

Comment: Cool.  I downloaded the latest jQuery, and have included it like so:  javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.1.js' 

in my application.html.erb

Where would I put the above javascript?  (sorry if that's a dumb question, this is all pretty new to me)

Comment: I guess I'm asking, would I be creating a file called, say home.js, and only putting that in it if that's the only javascript i want to use?  (assuming the route we are talking aobut is currently home.html.erb...)

Comment: You can create a Javascript file against every view (e.g. for my_application.html.erb, you can have my_application.js) and include all the Javascript relevant to that page in that file. There are some performance issues with this approach but I think it's a good start. Then you can include in in your my_application.html.erb just like you includes jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You will need JavaScript if you want to avoid reloading the page. You can use `link_to` for links in your lists, and you'll need to use `:remote => true` to make it send AJAX requests to the server. The server will need to respond appropriately and supply HTML for your div.

`link_to` documentation is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to (and admittedly it isn't very useful for AJAX functionality).

The last post in [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/211467) shows one possible solution you could use.